# How do I reach the top of this tower with the Hallowed Health in E2M6: The Erebus Reactor?

Tags: dusk

In **Episode 2 Mission 6: The Erebus Reactor** of **Dusk** there's collection of tall towers with metal girders connecting them all through the stage. There's quite a few items found throughout these towers and girders, and although I've found most of them, I have no idea how to reach one of them containing a Hallowed Health (pictured below).

[image: dusk hallowed health e2m6]

I'm assuming I need to take that top girder connecting the left most and right most tower, but I can't even figure out how to reach there. I've tried everything I can think of, including trying to drop down on top of one of these towers via another secret, which teleports me really high up in the stage. I thought about trying to bring a bunch of boxes, but not only does that seem way too tedious be the solution, I know I'd just wind up knocking  them all over anyway (too narrow of a spot).

How do I reach this Hallowed Health atop a tower in  **E2M6: The Erebus Reactor**?

Comment: Posting this since I had no luck tracking this down myself until I just looked up all secrets for the level. Not ideal, since it can accidently ruin other secrets which I'd rather just track down on my own, or leave without finding. Figured this should help anyone else stuck on this particular secret, without forcing them to spoil al the other secrets too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So the solution is to leverage a mechanic I didn't even realize existed, crossbow jumping. If you aim towards the ground with a crossbow and then fire, it'll jump you up a short distance into the air. You can chain crossbow bolts together to eventually reach the top of this tower.

So what you need to do is to just get right next to the pillar using one of the other two connecting girders you can actually reach, aim down with a crossbow, and then fire until you're high enough to reach the top of the tower.

[image: Crossbow Shannigans]

[Gif source](https://youtu.be/0PcmO3TG8jo?t=88).